# Error handling in time-limited Prolog meta-call

Tags: prolog, timeout

I am writing a predicate that implements a meta-call which imposes a limit on the time spent executing a goal—similar to `time_out/3` offered by `library(timeout)` on [SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002dtimeout.html) and [SWI-Prolog](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dialect/sicstus/timeout.pl).

Goals that would otherwise take forever ...

```
?- repeat, false.
% does not terminate
```

... can be aborted after some given time:

```
?- my_time_out((repeat,false), 1.0, S).
% answer after roughly one second
S = time_out.
```

OK! But there's a catch: calls to `my_time_out/3` may *not* be nested<sup>1</sup>.

So here's my challenge:

> Which error should `my_time_out/3` raise with nested use cases?

Right now, `error(resource_error(timer),_)` is getting thrown.

But are there better alternatives?

---

<sub>Footnotes:</sub>

<sup>**1**
This is due to arcane implementation details, but suffice it to say that this restriction is almost irrelevant to my target application. Still, this "almost" is bugging me...</sup>

Comment: Nesting is possible in SICStus but not in SWI.

Comment: @false. Really? The SWI manual says "Calls to time_out/3 can be nested." How come you say it is not?